# How Should the following table be Normalized?

Tags: sql, database

I have a table called `Employee` with `ID`,`Fname`,`Lname`,`dateEmployed`,`Program`, `fieldOfStudy`,`Salary`,`jobTitle` and `JobDescription` columns. I need to **Normalize it but i am not sure how to do that**. So how should i normalize it?
**This is what i have tried**
I created two tables `Employee` and `Job` as shown below and referenced the `jobId` column from `Job` table in `Employee` table.
here is `Employee Table`

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(
    Id int primary key identity,
    FName nvarchar(50),
    LName nvarchar(50),
    dateEmployed Date,
    jobID int foreign key references job(jbId)
);
```

here is the `Job Table`

```
CREATE TABLE Job(
    jobId int primary key identity,
    Title nvarchar(200),
    program nvarchar(30),
    salary float,
    fieldOfStudy nvarchar(50)
    JobDescription nvarchar(max)
);
```

**My Question is just about `Normalization` not on `sql query`**

Comment: As per your requirement, you will have for 1 job there will be one or more employees. if that is the case, the above structure will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question actually breaks down to : what is the relationship between jobs and employees (which you did not thoroughly explained). Possible cases are :

- **1-N** : if each employee has one job and several employees can have the same job, the your setup with two tables and a foreign key in employee towards job is fine
- **1-1** : if each employee has one job, and each job belongs to a single employee, then you do not need two tables : you can just stuff everything in the employee table
- **N-N** : if an employee can have several jobs, and each job can belong to several employees, then you would need to create a third table, a bridge table to represent that relationship, where each row would store one foreign key towards the jobs table and another towards the employees table

Comment: i didn't explain the relationships because i have been given just the sql table and asked to normalize it.

Comment: @Qwerty : ok, then you should ask for information about the relationship first, and then accordingly pick the relevant design, based on the decision tree I provided you with.